# php javascript html, why doesn't this work?

Tags: php, javascript, html, arrays, mysqli

Here is my code. I am trying to connect to my database and make a "joke of the day", so every day it will show a different joke. I've looked through my code several times and can't find out why it's not working.

```
<div id="joke">
This is the Joke of the Day:
<script>
var jokesArray = new Array ();
<?php
$jokeid = 1;
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","nick-website-database") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));
$temp = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `jokes`");
$i = 0;
while($joke = mysqli_fetch_array($temp)) {
    echo "jokesArray[".$i."]='" . $joke["description"]."';" ;
    $i++;
}
?>
var x=new Date();
var d(d.getDay());
if (d === 0) {
    document.write(jokesArray[0];
}
else if (d === 1) {
    document.write(jokesArray[1];
}
    else if (d === 2) {
    document.write(jokesArray[2];
}
    else if (d === 3) {
    document.write(jokesArray[3];
}
    else if (d === 4) {
    document.write(jokesArray[4];
}
    else if (d === 5) {
    document.write(jokesArray[5];
}
    else if (d === 6) {
    document.write(jokesArray[6];
}

</script>
</div>
```

Comment: What about it isn't working? Are you getting any errors, have you checked that the script is writing correctly, etc?

Comment: Also, please edit your title to express your problem and not to add tags.

Comment: You should do that on the server, not the client.

Comment: Also, you've got tons of syntax errors in your Javascript.

Comment: it's supposed to print the joke according to the date but it's not printing anything and it doesn't give any errors

Comment: This question is lacking a [mcve] and can be put on hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP has a getdate() function. See the documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getdate.php). Use conditionals for the date in the PHP code instead of in javascript, then simply "echo jokesarray[x]" where you need it.

Answer (score 5):

First of all fix this:

```
var x=new Date();
var d(d.getDay());
```

to

```
var x = new Date();
var d  = x.getDay();
```

Second, everytime you have this `document.write(jokesArray[1];` you are not closing it, like this:

```
document.write(jokesArray[1]);
```

and instead of doing that **HUGE** if statement block, just do this, which is the same.

```
document.write(jokesArray[d]);
```

Comment: I fixed all the syntax errors but still doesn't print anything

Answer (score 3):

All of your document.write's only have an open bracket, you need to close the bracket before the ;

**EDIT:**
Also fix this, you have the date variable wrong

```
var x=new Date();
var d(d.getDay());
```

needs to be

```
var x = new date();
var d = x.getDay();
```

Javascript is a funny language in the sense that something so simple will break without giving you a warning, try using firefox to debug javascript.

Example:

```
Your Current Code:

if (d === 0) {
  document.write(jokesArray[0];
}
else if (d === 1) {
  document.write(jokesArray[1];
}
else if (d === 2) {
  document.write(jokesArray[2];
}
else if (d === 3) {
  document.write(jokesArray[3];
}
else if (d === 4) {
  document.write(jokesArray[4];
}
else if (d === 5) {
  document.write(jokesArray[5];
}
else if (d === 6) {
  document.write(jokesArray[6];
}
```

You need it like this:

```
The Correct Code:

    if (d === 0) {
  document.write(jokesArray[0]);
}
else if (d === 1) {
  document.write(jokesArray[1]);
}
else if (d === 2) {
  document.write(jokesArray[2]);
}
else if (d === 3) {
  document.write(jokesArray[3]);
}
else if (d === 4) {
  document.write(jokesArray[4]);
}
else if (d === 5) {
  document.write(jokesArray[5]);
}
else if (d === 6) {
  document.write(jokesArray[6]);
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I just realized that but it still doesn't work after I closed them all

Answer (score -1):

Ok i figured it out. It was a problem with my database. I had apostrophes and dashes in the values so it screwed up the rest of the code. Thanks anyways!